# SQL Server Availability Groups

Tags: sql-server

I've got a server with a number of databases in an availability group. This has been setup prior to me joining the company and I'm not that familiar with SQL Server. A question has been asked if we can failover a single database or all in the availability group. How do I check if this is possible, or is there any SQL I can run to get some configuration details?

Answer (score 0):

All of the databases in an Availability Group failover at the same time. This is by design as the AG is the effective container.

If you would like to do a manual failover then refer to the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/perform-a-planned-manual-failover-of-an-availability-group-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)